# HBase and Tephra. Incompatible api

Tags: hadoop, transactions, hbase

I use HBase DB and I want to have transaction support. I found Tephra technology and as I can see it is still under development. My version of HBase is 1.1.4. Thephra version is the newest one 0.7.0. On the main documentation of tephra - https://github.com/caskdata/tephra I can see that we should use this client code.

```
TransactionContext context = new TransactionContext(client,transactionAwareHTable);
try {
     context.start();
     transactionAwareHTable.put(new Put(Bytes.toBytes("row"));
     // ...
     context.finish();
} catch (TransactionFailureException e) {
    context.abort();
}
```

But in order to get transactionAwareHTable I should use:

```
private Connection connection = ....
TransactionAwareHTable transactionAwareHTable = new TransactionAwareHTable(connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf("Nodes")));
```

Problem is that Tephra API requires HConnection instead Connection and HTable instead Table(HConnection and HTable are depreciated). I can't see soultion for that incompaticle interfaces. Any ideas how to resolve that?

Comment: If you want Table and Conection support, maybe you could either do it yourself (it is git after all), or fill a ticket to ask about it. By the way, I don't think it is not compatible for the moment

Comment: Of course I know I can do sth like adapter but I'm wondering that maybe there is existing solution for that. As I can see in the last compat-1.1 module there are still depreciated methods used.

Comment: @DanielUrbaniak did you find any resolution? or any alternative working transaction layers?